# Android: How to size buttons?

Tags: android, layout, button

I'm using several buttons in my app, but both layout_width/height "wrap_content" and "fill_parent" looks weird. The former being to small and the latter too large - both looks weird, and the former is not easy to hit with your finger.

How should I size buttons? Is it typical to define their sizes in dip? Or should I use "fill_parent" with a padding? Buttons looks weird in my app, not so in others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is difficult to answer in the abstract. Here are some techniques to consider:

- Use `android:padding="4dip"` (or some other value) to make a `wrap_content` `Button` a bit bigger
- Use `android:textSize` on the `Button` to make the content bigger (use some size in scaled pixels, or `sp`)
- If you want the buttons to fill the space but divide it among themselves, use a `LinearLayout`, give each button a height (or width, depending if column or row) of `0px`, then use `android:layout_weight` to allocate space between them on a percentage basis. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Containers/LinearPercent) outlining this technique.

Comment: OK. I ended up using paddingLeft and paddingRight of 20dip and paddingTop and paddingBottom of 10dip. Looks good that way and should be flexible with both layout changes and translation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use fill_parent with a padding/margin instead an exact width value. So you are more flexible when the size of the parent view changes.