# Eclipse android widget moving

Tags: java, android, widget

I am designing my activity screen using eclipse but whenever I move an object e.g. a button it snaps around and I find it hard to position things where i want them.

Is there some setting I can change as as soon as I add a second button it snaps the other button to another position it is so annoying!

Also if I have an image button why can't i resize this, even with a normal button if i try to make it larger it just fits to the text and wont make the button bigger or it just flicks to a random place on the activity?

thanks

Comment: dont use that stupid ui editor, it adds more garbage than real code, write your layouts by hand

Comment: You can change the width height and almost any position by code. I suggest you to use code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're trying to place components freely in the View but you're not considering the LayoutManager behavior. If you try to position your component in a LinearLayout, for example, the components will be placed following its rules, and these components will not stay where you drop them.

Try to understand better [how the layouts works on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). But for now, the [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) or [RelativeLayout](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) may be what you're looking for.

About the components size, you'll need to understand better how to use layout properties for these components. See the question [How to size buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533728/android-how-to-size-buttons) for more information.